# parsing with recursion - brackets

Tags: c, parsing, recursion, brackets

Could some give me a hint at this problem : 
An expression is correct only if it contains parentheses and braces properly closed and no other character, even space. For example, () ({} () ({})) is a correct expression, whereas ({)} is not a correct expression or {} ({})). An empty expression (which does not contain any character) is correct.
Given a string expression determine if the expressions is correct and if is determine the maximum level of nesting. Maximum level of nesting parentheses is the maximum number of one another.

Examples
{}({}){{(({}))}}
answer : 5

{}({})) -1 (because the expression is incorrect)

That's what I've did so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fi, *fo;
int first, er;

void X();
void Y();

void S() {
    X();
    Y();
}
void X() {
    if(first=='{') {
        first=fgetc(fi);
        X();
        if(first=='}')
            first=fgetc(fi);
        else
            er=1;
        S();
    }
}
void Y() {
    if(first=='(') {
        first=fgetc(fi);
        Y();
        if(first==')')
            first=fgetc(fi);
        else
            er=1;
        S();
    }
}
int main()
{
    fi = fopen("brackets.in","r");
    fo = fopen("brackets.out","w");
    first=fgetc(fi);
    S();
    if(first!='\n')
        er=-1;
    fprintf(fo,"%d",er);
    fclose(fi);
    fclose(fo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `stack data structure` and a `max_nesting` variable.keep pushing all the open brackets until you find close brackets.As soon as you get close bracket update `max_nesting`.if it is greater than previous value update `max_nesting`.

Comment: I can't use suplimentar memory. The memory have to be O(1). The solution must be with parsing

Comment: @riic2000 aw and I was going to put together a O(n) dynamic programming solution.

Comment: riic2000, I am skeptical that you are required to solve this in O(1) supplemental memory.  Near as I can tell, that cannot be done, because you need to keep a state around somehow, and the state needs to keep track of what order the braces were opened in to verify closing order, and that's O(n).  Even if you use the string itself to do it, that's still O(n) memory.

Comment: That's what it says, memory must be O(1)...

Comment: I'm with @OmnipotentEntity - I don't believe this can be done with only `O(1)` memory. Even a recursive-descent parser type solution would have to use additional memory linearly related to the maximum nesting level, even if it's not explicitly allocated (i.e. recursive calls require additional stack frames)... Now, maybe if the input came in string form, instead of by character, you could use the string itself and erasures to avoid *additional* memory, but that doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: I don't understand the constraint *and no other character, even space*. Your example `() ({} () ({}))` contains spaces in the second set of `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it helps to think of your problem as a formal grammar.

```
S = The Language you are testing for

S->
  NUL    // Empty   
  SS     // S followed by itself.   
  [ S ]  // Case 1   
  ( S )  // Case 2   
  { S }  // Case 3
```

Since this grammar only has one symbol (S), you only need one parsing method.

The following code is incomplete but hopefully it gets the idea across.

```
char curr_char;

int main (void)
{
  curr_char = getc();
  result = parse_s();
  return 0;
}

// Parse the S pattern off input.  When this method completes, curr_char points to the character AFTER S.
// Returns recursion count or -1 on fail.
int parse_s()
{
  max_count = 0;
  while(true)
  {
    int curr_count = 0;
    switch 'curr_char':
    {
      case '[': // [
        int count = parse_s(); // S
        if (count == -1) return -1;  // The S must be valid
        if (curr_char != ']') return -1;  // ]
        curr_char = getc();  // Advance past the ]
        curr_count = count + 1;  // This expression is 1 nest greater than its contained S
      break;

      case '(':
        // XXX
      break;

      case '{':
        // XXX
      break;

      default:
        // This is either the SS (find the max of the two), the NUL case (return 0), or an error (return -1)
      break;
    }
    // In the SS case you're gonna have to loop and do something here.
  }
  return max_count;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I've came back. I used your model, but I can't find how to modify the following code because it displays the number of acoldes and brackets instead of maxim grade of imbrication. I'll put the code in the post, so you can see better